# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'poetry.console' when trying to uninstall poetry

Tags: python, uninstallation, python-poetry, modulenotfounderror

First of all I ran `poetry update` which seemed to work. To verify if it actually updated my poetry version I ran `poetry --version` which resulted in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\XXX\.poetry\bin\poetry", line 17, in <module>
from poetry.console import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'poetry.console'
```

To solve this error, uninstalling poetry appeared the best option. So I tried uninstalling poetry by `python get-poetry.py --uninstall` and `python install-poetry.py --uninstall`. Both resulted in `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Furthermore, I tried `poetry --uninstall` which resulted also in the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

How can I uninstall poetry and why are my commands not working?

Answer (score 2):

`get-poetry.py` and `install-poetry.py` are the installer scripts and have to be downloaded first. You can combine downloading and running in one line, e.g.:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python - --uninstall
```

or

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --uninstall
```

for uninstalling poetry. For uninstalling you have to use the same script you have used for installing.

Comment: Along with this make sure you do not have any path in which poetry.exe exists, in my case another poetry file existed  at Python39\Scripts after deleting it fixed.